# Does getline in C++ just take string type?

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline

I have this code to read from file and it works.

```
#include "cppstd.hh"
#include <string>

int main(){
  string line;
  string *vdata= new string[10];
  ifstream fvecin ("vector.txt");
  if (fvecin.is_open()){
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
      getline(fvecin,line);
      vdata[i]=line;
      cout << "vdata["<<i<<"]="<< line << endl;
      }
    }
  else{
    cout << "ERROR: Cannot open the file!" << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

However, when I changed to int line, int *vdata = new int[10],(or double) it does not work and have this error:

```
ifstream_test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
ifstream_test.cc:10:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘getline(std::ifstream&, int&)’
ifstream_test.cc:10:26: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/stdio.h:675:20: note: __ssize_t getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*)
/usr/include/stdio.h:675:20: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2734:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::getline(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.tcc:1070:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::getline(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, _CharT)
```

Could you suggest the way that I can read from file that contains data of any types (double, float, etc). Thank you so much.

Comment: Does the file store these values in a binary format or a text format?

Answer (score 0):

> Could you suggest the way that I can read from file that contains data
>   of any types (double, float, etc).

How about trying like this:

```
ifstream inf;
double d;
int n, m;

inf.open("foo.txt", ios::in);

inf >> d >> n >> m;

inf.close();
```

Also check [Input/Output with files](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)

Comment: @user2969181:- You may accept this as an answer if that worked for you :)

Comment: I think the suggestion of using inf >> was helpful. I actually had now known this before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> ReadFile( std::string fname)
{

  std::vector<T> vec;
  std::ifstream fvecin (fname.c_str());
  if (fvecin.is_open()){
   std::copy(std::istream_iterator<T>(fvecin),
             std::istream_iterator<T>(), std::back_inserter(vec) );
    }
  else{
    std::cout << "ERROR: Cannot open the file!" << std::endl;
  }
return vec;
}
```

And then,

```
#define READ_TYPE float //change type here
int main(){

std::vector<READ_TYPE> v;
  v=ReadFile<READ_TYPE>(std::string("input.txt"));

for(auto i:v)
std::cout<<i<<" "<<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

See ['here'](http://ideone.com/Ic84op) (used `std::cin` instead of `std::ifstream`)